# Why does turning off Auto Smooth removes blotches?

Tags: modeling, normals

Often with imported OBJ meshes I noticed that some seemingly random vertices are surrounded in dark blotches and sometimes adjacent ones are pale. Yet all the readable characteristics are identical to a normal vert angle stats. So why when I was messing around I unchecked Auto Smooth did theses anomalies go away?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the mesh with auto smooth on and then off please?

Comment: Auto smooth will create strange shading when dealing with non planar geometry (specially ngons), or when the amount of vertices is too low to achieve proper curvature of a set of faces. Please upload an image of your particular issue.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes had effects like this because custom split normals data was imported and got distorted somehow. AutoSmooth only seems to work reliably if this data is deleted, try the button in the Mesh Data section to clear custom split normals data:

[image: clear custom split normals data]