# Hair mesh shader issue

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, transparency, shader-nodes

I'm new to blender trying to import some hair meshes. I'd be grateful if someone could explain why the transparencies look fine in mat preview and eevee but not cycles, and how to fix this.

[image: hair setup]

Here is the blend file https://www.mediafire.com/file/482hk07aqvfrn7i/hair002.blend/file

Edit: I opened the blend in 2.8 (original is 3.2) and see a better result[image].

Comment: It's the stacked transparency of these so-called hair cards that cause the black areas in Cycles. The render engines Cycles and Eevee calculate transparency differently. (And the Material Preview mode is very similar to Eevee.) You need to increase the setting *Light Path > Max Bounces > Transparent* in the Cycles render settings: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/42023/107598

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried doing that previously, the transparent bounces don't seem to effect the render much at all past 30 and looks pretty much the same maxed out at 1024. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if you could confirm with the blend file

Comment: Two more things:
**1.** the *Normal Map* node is missing. Add it between the *Image Texture* node and the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*. Don't forget the *Scalp_Scalp.dmx* object. It's missing there, too.
**2.** The imported mesh has *Auto Smooth* enabled and uses *Custom Split Normal Data*. This causes shading issues. (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/60592/107598). Turn it off in *Object Data Properties (tab) > Normals*

Comment: If you only use a transparency shader in the material (=full transparency/invisible mesh) you can check how many bounces you need to remove the black areas. It's 59 bounces for me. The mesh is optimized for game engines and has double planes to counter the backface culling. I would not remove doubles because that introduces new shading issues. In the material setting, you only need the *Principled BSDF* when you connect the *Alpha* from the *Image Texture* node into the *Alpha* slot of the *P.BSDF*. The *Transparency* and the *MixShader* nodes can be removed then.